# Wrong caret position on text editors on web

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I'm having this issue i dont know what to do to solve it, not found relevant information on web

I have the same behavior on Chrome and Firefox. currently I'm using KDE Plasma, but also same problem with Gnome

I've tried changing my default monospaced font but nothing solve the problem

it happens on editors like this one https://ace.c9.io/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as you. I changed "Noto Mono" to "DejaVu Sans Mono" in "monospace" in my /etc/fonts/local.conf.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>      
    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family"><string>monospace</string></test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same"><string>DejaVu Sans Mono</string></edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```